# Does ASIHTTP run javascript code?

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I am planning on calling a php jason script from ASIHTTP. I am planning on putting Google Analytics code in the script so that I can track its usage in Google Analytics.

I was wondering, if I load a PHP script from my server, will the Java script code be executed or not?

If not, is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Would it be so hard to test this yourself?

Comment: The best way to answer this question is to just do it yourself. Write a PHP script on your server which executes some javascript code and then displays a popup dialog box, and then run the ASIHTTPRequest demo app provided for you and access the script from it.

Answer (score 1):

No. ASIHTTP does not include any Javascript parser or interpreter.